# Showing html file using UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have created a `UIWebView` and used a HTML file to display some contents. But when I run it instead of showing the contents only the whole HTML file coding is coming in the WebView. Please help and tell me what is wrong.

```
UIWebView *ingradients= [[UIWebView alloc]init];
    [ingradients setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 170, 300, 300)];
    [ingradients loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"htmlfile" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
    ingradients.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:ingradients];
```

My **htmlfile.html** contains

```
<html>
<body>
<p><strong>Ingredients</strong></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of showing "Ingredients" in bold its showing the whole coding of **htmlfile.html**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Your code you alway contain HTML code because your request always return file `htmlfile` with extantion `.html`

If you want to get specific value from `HTML` content you need to **Parce** `HTML` content by using [`Hpple`](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple). Also This is [documentation with exmple](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios)  that are use for parse `HTML` content.

**In your case you use: (***by using `Hpple`*)

```
TFHpple *dataParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:placesData];

    // name of place
NSString *XpathQueryString = @"//p/strong";
NSArray *listOfdata= [dataParser searchWithXPathQuery: XpathQueryString];
```

Comment: just now i have noticed that when i open that html file in a browser also its showing the whole coding. can you tell me what will be the problem?

Comment: i actually tried **loadHTMLstring** method and put the html coding there as string parameter and its working fine.... :)

Answer (score 2):

That's weird, I have similar code for this and html is rendered as rich text but not as plain text (like you have), the only difference I have is using `fileURLWithPath:` but not `fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:`. Here's my code:

```
NSString *localFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"about" ofType:@"html"];
NSURLRequest *localRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:localFilePath]];
[_aboutWebView loadRequest:localRequest];
```

Maybe you have some issues with file encoding, but as far as I guess, that should not be the case.

Comment: just now i have noticed that when i open that html file in a browser also its showing the whole coding. can you tell me what will be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
- (NSString *) rootPath{
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}

- (NSString *) pathFoResourse : (NSString *) resourseName ofType: (NSString *)type{
    NSString *path = [[MMSupport rootPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", resourseName, type]];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resourseName ofType:type];
    }
    NSLog(@"**path:%@**", path);
    return path;
}

- (void) loadDataToWebView : (CGRect) frame{
    NSString *htmlString =  [NSstring stringWithContentsOfFile:[MMSupport pathFoResourse:@"filename" ofType:@"html"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) error:nil];
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
}
```